# Cache object without it being a side effect [Play Framework]

Tags: java, playframework, functional-programming, playframework-2.0, side-effects

This question is in reference to Play 2.2 Java.

I have a list of items that is retrieved from a web service. The list will be required frequently, so I am caching the list locally.

I have set up a method that client code may call to get the list transparently. The method will first check the cache, falling back to the web service if the list is not present locally.

The issue I have is in regenerating the cached list from the web service. I can't use the `Cache.getOrElse` method, because it requires an instance of the list, and the `Play.libs.WS` returns a `Promise<WS.Response>` that I map to a `Promise<List>`.

My current strategy looks like the following:

1. Query the cache for the list, and return the result wrapped in a `Promise`
2. Flatmap the `Promise`, returning the wrapped list if present, or calling the web service adapter, and returning the returned `Promise<List>`

Now, before I return the `Promise` from the web service adapter in step 2, I register a callback on the promise to add the list to the cache when it is redeemed.

What I want to know is: is there a way that I can add the list form the web service to the cache, without it being a side effect of the process?

I had tried another strategy, where I mapped the returned `Promise`, cached it, and returned the list, but that seems like an even more blatant side effect. I'd like to avoid that if I can.